# Using Python, how can I access a shared folder on windows network?

Tags: python, windows, networking

I have a file that I would like to copy from a shared folder which is in a shared folder on a different system, but on the same network. How can I access the folder/file? The usual open() method does not seem to work?

Comment: If you have correct permissions to access it, then I think regular open should work...

Comment: How can I do?. I have the username and password to the shared folder. What would be the code?

Answer (score 125, accepted):

Use forward slashes to specify the [UNC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29#Uniform_Naming_Convention) Path:

```
open('//HOST/share/path/to/file')
```

(if your Python client code is also running under Windows)

Comment: This just solved a problem that was annoying me, thanks!

Comment: This only works on Windows (yes, the question is tagged Windows, but accessing a Windows server from non-Windows OS may also be tagged as such).  Anyone care to add a solution for other platforms (e.g. Linux) - if possible without something like Samba?

Comment: @DavidJ If you're using SMB on Linux, I'd expect `//HOST/share/` to be mounted (somewhere like `/mnt/share`) and the file to be opened like a regular file (`open('/mnt/share/path/to/file')`).

Comment: DavidJ Did you try @Johnsyweb solution? Did it work?

Comment: @Johnsyweb have you got another solution for this somewhere? Possibly github so I can view and re-use? I'm on a MAC trying to hit a shared network address. It is mounted - I have followed all solutions on this place all are giving FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

Comment: @AzySır I'm afraid I do not. I would expect `//HOST/share/` to be mounted (somewhere like `/Volumes/share`) and the file to be opened like a regular file (`open('/Volumes/share/path/to/file')`).

Comment: @Johnsyweb my issue is im on OSX trying to open up a WINDOWS Network Server. It's saying not found even though it is evidently mounted - not sure how to proceed on it

Comment: if you are on MacOS, and you've mounted your server via Go > Connect to Server, you should be able to see your server if you use os.listdir("/Volumes/")

Comment: @AzySır I'm having a similar issue. Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 48):

How did you try it? Maybe you are working with `\` and omit proper escaping.

Instead of

```
open('\\HOST\share\path\to\file')
```

use either Johnsyweb's solution with the `/`s, or try one of

```
open(r'\\HOST\share\path\to\file')
```

or

```
open('\\\\HOST\\share\\path\\to\\file')
```

.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue as OP but none of the current answers solved my issue so to add a slightly different answer that did work for me:

Running Python 3.6.5 on a Windows Machine, I used the format

```
r"\\DriveName\then\file\path\txt.md"
```

so the combination of double backslashes from reading @Johnsyweb UNC link and adding the r in front as recommended solved my similar to OP's issue.

Answer (score 1):

My remote server is on Linux Machine and the client on Windows. For me:

1. `glob.glob('//HOST/share/path/to/file')` works with forward slash
2. `open(r'\\HOST\share\path\to\file')` and `open('\\\\HOST\\share\\path\\to\\file')` worked with backward slash
3. For `pd.read_csv()`, forward or backward slash, doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Slight twist on the other answers: I was testing and needed to check if a remote file existed or not.  I found this code did the trick

```
try:  
    #  
    f = open(r'\\<server name>\<folder>\<filename>')  
    print("found file")  
    f.close()  
except:  
    print("file not seen")
```

That 'close' is always a good idea (certainly in my case, where all I'm doing is checking presence).