# Python 3.4 and Windows Shared File Paths

Tags: windows, python-3.4, fileshare

I am trying to open a file in a shared network location

```
open('\\int\GroupData\ITProSup\Operations Support\REMGROUP.txt','+r')
```

Now this turns into

```
nemonics>python main.py
eback (most recent call last):
le "main.py", line 41, in <module>
sys.exit(main())
le "main.py", line 36, in main
insert_file_into_db(con_S104838,open('\\int\GroupData\ITProSup\Operations Su
t\REMGROUP.txt','+r'))
NotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '\\int\\GroupData\\ITPro
\Operations Support\\REMGROUP.txt'
```

I have tried this thread [Using Python, how can I access a shared folder on windows network?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7169845/using-python-how-can-i-access-a-shared-folder-on-windows-network) but it does note seem to work for me. I am running python 3.4.1 and its windows 2012 server.

I have also tried using os.path https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/os.path.html#os.path.normpath with not much luck

```
C:\mnemonics>python main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 41, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "main.py", line 36, in main
    insert_file_into_db(con_S104838, open(os.path.normpath('\\int\GroupData\ITPr
oSup\Operations Support\REMGROUP.txt')))
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '\\int\\GroupData\\ITPro
Sup\\Operations Support\\REMGROUP.txt'

C:\mnemonics>python main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 42, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "main.py", line 37, in main
    open(os.path.normcase('\\int\GroupData\ITProSup\Operations Support\REMGROUP.
txt'),'+r'))
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '\\int\\groupdata\\itpro
sup\\operations support\\remgroup.txt'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: `print('\\foo')` will print out `\foo`. Use forward slashes instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `\` should be escaped to `\\`, so `\\` should be `\\\\`

Please try

```
'\\\\int\\GroupData\\ITProSup\\Operations Support\\REMGROUP.txt'
```

or

```
'//int/GroupData/ITProSup/Operations Support/REMGROUP.txt'
```

Comment: turns out it was security access stopping me from accessing the shared drive. The user I ran it under didn't have visibility of this shared drive. Cheers for the reply your methods worked once I had security access to the drive