# IPython Notebook - saving notebook fails

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

Saving my IPython notebook fails.

I've set up a folder on a network drive which I'd like to save my notebooks to, but it isn't quite cooperating yet.

In `ipython_notebook_config.py` I've edited the following lines:

```
c.NotebookManager.notebook_dir = u'Z:\\Analytics\\Work\\MyFolder'
c.FileNotebookManager.notebook_dir = u'Z:\\Analytics\\Work\\MyFolder'
c.NotebookApp.notebook_dir = u'Z:\\Analytics\\Work\\MyFolder'
```

but still no joy.

This is IPython 2.1.0

I'm a little new to Python and IPython Notebook, so this may be obvious, not sure.

The following is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
File \"C:\\Anaconda\\lib\\site-packages\\IPython\\html\\base\\handlers.py\", line 286, in wrapper    
    result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)  
File \"C:\\Anaconda\\lib\\site-packages\\IPython\\html\\services\\notebooks\\handlers.py\", line 209, in put
    self._save_notebook(model, path, name)  
File \"C:\\Anaconda\\lib\\site-packages\\IPython\\html\\services\\notebooks\\handlers.py\", line 145, in _save_notebook
    model = self.notebook_manager.save_notebook(model, name, path)
File \"C:\\Anaconda\\lib\\site-packages\\IPython\\html\\services\\notebooks\\filenbmanager.py\", line 289, in save_notebook
    self.create_checkpoint(name, path)  
File \"C:\\Anaconda\\lib\\site-packages\\IPython\\html\\services\\notebooks\\filenbmanager.py\", line 433, in create_checkpoint    
    os.mkdir(self.checkpoint_dir)\nWindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied: u'.ipynb_checkpoints'
```

EDIT:

Thanks to Simon Smith below I tracked it down.

Checkpoints were still saving to the wrong place.  I changed this line in the config:

```
c.FileNotebookManager.checkpoint_dir = r'Z:\Analytics\Work\MyFolder\.ipynb_checkpoints'
```

and now I'm sailing along.  I've also edited the other paths to be `r'such and such'` as well.  Thanks again.

Comment: did you check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7169845/using-python-how-can-i-access-a-shared-folder-on-windows-network)?

Comment: @goncalopp I hadn't, and I just did, but it didn't pan out.  In fact, it looks like it absolutely hates the UNC flavor path.  It wouldn't even start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final line looks suspicious here:

> os.mkdir(self.checkpoint_dir)\nWindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied: u'.ipynb_checkpoints'

This looks like a permissions issue on that directory (i.e. ipython can't write any data to that location). There are instructions on how to change them [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-files/how-do-i-change-folder-and-file-permissions/465f2b42-63dd-4486-8dd1-c870290efeed?auth=1).

Comment: Ok this sort of got me going in the right direction.  I don't have write access on my local PC outside of my user directory, which is where the checkpoints were defaulting to.  I had to find this line in the profile: `c.FileNotebookManager.checkpoint_dir` and set it as well.  It was still trying to write to some local directory rather than the network path I specified.  Thanks for pointing that out.