# How can i download and save file from fileserver in python

Tags: python, windows, request

I am using python and requests library.

I have my file generated on intranet fileserver with url like

```
url = "\\\\int\\appdata\\test\\data.txt"
```

If directly tupe that in browser , it saves the files. but i want to download the file using python

`requests.get(url)`

says invalid url

Comment: Doesn't your browser auto-convert that URL to use the 'file:///' protocol?

Comment: @willnx yes i think browser does that . I even tried file:/// in requests as well but it does not work

Answer (score 0):

[Using Python, how can I access a shared folder on windows network?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7170008/5389781)

Use forward slashes to specify the UNC Path:

```
open('//HOST/share/path/to/file')
```