# Accessing UNC drives with Python

Tags: python, unc

Our office is switching soon to Universal Naming Convention sharedrive shortcuts and getting rid of most mapped sharedrives. I am trying to access the UNC shortcuts and I am having no luck. When I try os.chdir(<'The UNC shortcut'>) I get the usual WindowsError about how it cant find the drive. I need to access the drives to run analysis on data.

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7169845/using-python-how-can-i-access-a-shared-folder-on-windows-network

Comment: Well that was a good idea but I got an IOError Permission denied message. I think they have this pretty locked up. I still have the mapped drives for now, otherwise we may have to have a talk with IT.