# Python's os.scandir() is not recognizing my network path

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module

I saw a question on here somewhat like mine, but the solution there did not work.

My code is:

```
for filename in os.scandir('\\\\network_drive\\folder\\folder\\folder\\'):
    print(filename)
```

The error is:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 67] The network name cannot be found:
    '\\\\network_drive\\folder\\folder\\folder\\'
```

The network drive's path is definitely correct (I copied/pasted straight out of Windows Explorer's address bar).  Am I syntactically screwing up or is this possibly a permissions problem via Active Directory?  I'm seriously not understanding what I'm screwing up.

**Update:**  I can't even map the network folder to a drive on my machine, leading me to think this is an AD issue.  I've contacted my IT department to see if they can help resolve the issue.

**Update:** It was an AD issue; IT team fixed the issue, just forgot to update... 3 years ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

```
os.scandir('//network_drive/folder/folder/folder/')
```

See [this answer to an earlier question.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7170008/1672565)

Also, sometimes this may work

```
  with os.scandir('//network_drive/folder/folder/folder/') as it:
      for fnames in it:
          ...
```

Comment: It does not work. Just tried it out. It's looking more and more like an Active Directory issue. I can't even map that network drive to a drive on my desktop.

Comment: @dmcoding, if you are unable to map then you need to try that because your code looks right.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the below? It worked for me.

```
os.listdir('\\network_drive\c$\folder\folder\folder')
```

Comment: i haven't programmed in python in like a year and a half. i have no idea if this is correct or not because the script was abandoned/replaced and i don't even work there anymore.