# Why do I get FileNotFoundError (WinError 3), when using Path.rglob on Windows Python?

Tags: python, windows

I'm trying to get a list of all contents of a directory, `targetDir`, including files and subdirectories. For this I am using

```py
from pathlib import Path
targetDir = r"\\sharedDrive\folder1\folder2\folder3"
allTargets = Path(targetDir).rglob("*")
```

However, this returns the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: '\\\\sharedDrive\\folder1\\folder2\\folder3\\[...]\\folder10'
```

My best guess is that this is caused by Windows' 260 character path limit. The path mentioned in the traceback is 257 characters long. I have redacted the path for privacy.

## Troubleshooting:

I know the path exists, because I can see it in File Explorer. Moreover, `dir "\\sharedDrive\folder1\folder2\folder3\[...]\folder10"` returns

```
10/26/2020  12:01 PM    <DIR>          .
10/26/2020  12:01 PM    <DIR>          ..
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  367,916,392,448 bytes free
```

I can do

```py
os.listdir("\\sharedDrive\folder1")
```

and continue down each folder all the way to `folder9`:

```py
os.listdir("\\sharedDrive\folder1\folder2\folder3\[...]\folder9")
```

But at `folder10` I get the same `FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3]` error.

Also, when I do

```py
i = 0
j = 0
allTargets = Path(targetDir).rglob("*.*")
for _ in allTargets:
    i += 1
```

I get `i` as 27 817.

I'm doing this on Anaconda's IPython and Windows CMD Python:

```
Python 3.9.7 (default, Sep 16 2021, 16:59:28) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.29.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.
```

```
Python 3.10.2 (tags/v3.10.2:a58ebcc, Jan 17 2022, 14:12:15) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
```

## References

I've consulted these SO posts:

- [Python's os.scandir() is not recognizing my network path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47890647/pythons-os-scandir-is-not-recognizing-my-network-path)
- [FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51007476/filenotfounderror-winerror-3-the-system-cannot-find-the-path-specified)
- [How to use glob() to find files recursively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186525/how-to-use-glob-to-find-files-recursively)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why I get the error, but I deleted that one particular folder, `folder10`, and now `Path(targetDir).rglob("*")` finishes running and counts 178 616 files and subdirectories.

My best guess is that it was some weird Windows path limitation.