# How to copy file to windows network drive folder using python?

Tags: python, windows, copy, share

I try to copy txt file from WinPC1 to WinPC2

In my WinPC1 i created local txt file in:

```
C:\temp\1.txt
```

I want to copy that txt file to windows network drive to folder:

```
OUT\temp
```

WinPC2 on WinPC1 seen:

1. by **net use** like `nam1\\box1\\IKQ`
2. by explorer like `Z:\`

so full paths are:

1. full path witn **net use** will be `\\\\nam1\\box1\\IKQ\\OUT\\temp`
2. or in **explorer** will be `Z:\OUT\tmp`

First of all I tried to use **os**:

1. `copy C:\temp\1.txt Z:\OUT\tmp` - check it in cmd, it was sucsessfull
2. `os.system(r"copy C:\\temp\\1.txt Z:\\OUT\\tmp")` - try by python, it wasn't sucsessfull

Then I read about **shutil**, and try to use it: it didn't work too, try to copy like that:

1. `shutil.copy(r'C:\temp\1.txt', "Z:\OUT\tmp")`
2. `shutil.copy(r'C:\temp\1.txt', "\\\\nam1\\box1\\IKQ\\OUT\\temp")`

What i need to do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Python, how can I access a shared folder on windows network?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7169845/using-python-how-can-i-access-a-shared-folder-on-windows-network)

Comment: @PramitSawant tried that too

Comment: i think that main problem in authentication: if i disconnect network drive? to connect it i need a username/passoword it different with my local username/password on WinPC1 - maybe main problem in that me need to use not local but another user/pass in my py script?