# Can't open a .txt file

Tags: python, windows, file, network-share

So I was trying to learn the function `open` which is apparently easy to use. I copied a really simple code from a website to just open and read a file called "test.txt" with some text on it. I tried it both ways, not specifying the path (since it's in the same folder) and calling the whole path. None worked (`FileNotFoundError`). It's all in a server so that might be the problem but I'd still like a short explanation if that is the problem.
Go easy on the vocabulary please, I'm just taking the first steps.

On the image I tried to stack as much info as posible: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wtb5R.jpg).

```
handle = open("test.txt")
data = handle.read()
print(data)
handle.close()
```

SOLUTION: I actually just removed the .txt from the text file. Now it's name is test and it is a text file and the code works. I previously moved the python file and text file from the server to the computer since a comment said it could be the problem, but after finding my solution i put it all back in the server and the program runs as well.

Comment: Does `ls` works to find that file in the path you mentioned?

Comment: I dont know what ls means, sorry

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Python, how can I access a shared folder on windows network?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7169845/using-python-how-can-i-access-a-shared-folder-on-windows-network)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to open a file that is located on a network share (`\\Servidor\profiles$\...`) and you are accessing it by using the `\\<server>\<sharename>` syntax and not mounted as a Windows drive letter.

Some things you could try:

1. Copy the data from the network share to some local directory on **your** machine and run your script again.
2. Try [mounting the network share](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4026635/windows-map-a-network-drive) under a "drive letter" and run again using this drive letter.
3. Try this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7170008/8745384 if you really need to access it on the network share.

Comment: I went for option 1, since it looks like the esaiest one. I cut and paste the folder with both script and text file to the computer. Same error pops up. Here is the new exception: https://imgur.com/a/omhBGBa (sorry for linking the images, dont know how to insert them yet)

Comment: I think the new error is related to the windows-style backslash-path. Have a look on this article: https://medium.com/@ageitgey/python-3-quick-tip-the-easy-way-to-deal-with-file-paths-on-windows-mac-and-linux-11a072b58d5f