# How can I read/write data from/to network attached storage with kedro?

Tags: python, kedro

In the API docs about [`kedro.io`](https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/stable/kedro.io.html#) and [`kedro.contrib.io`](https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/stable/kedro.contrib.io.html) I could not find info about how to read/write data from/to network attached storage such as e.g. [FritzBox NAS](https://en.avm.de/guide/using-the-fritzbox-nas-function/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I'm a little rusty on network attached storage, but:

1. If you can mount your network attached storage onto your OS and access it like a regular folder, then it's just a matter of providing the right `filepath` when writing the config for a given catalog entry. See for example: [Using Python, how can I access a shared folder on windows network?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7169845/using-python-how-can-i-access-a-shared-folder-on-windows-network)
2. Otherwise, if accessing the network attached storage requires anything special, you might want to [create a custom dataset](https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/stable/04_user_guide/14_create_a_new_dataset.html) that uses a Python library for interfacing with your network attached storage. Something like [pysmb](https://pysmb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) comes to mind.

The custom dataset could borrow heavily from the logic in existing `kedro.io` or `kedro.extras.datasets` datasets, but you replace the filepath/fsspec handling code with `pysmb` instead.

Comment: Thanks. This helps a lot. On a linux machine one can auto mount into the local file system as well. https://github.com/Pantastisch/fritz_nas_auto_mount

Comment: Perfect. Looks like you can use any dataset and just provide `/mnt/fritz_nas/<NAS_PATH>` as the file path (for e.g). By the way, I'm curios -- what's the use case for putting datasets on a NAS?

Comment: Pls do not ask. :smile: The team wants to share raw data in the local network. Usually I'd setup a Minio based, S3-like blob storage in the local network. The kendro.io S3 functionality should work with it as is. However it's some constraint I've to work with.

Comment: I've created a class implementing just as much basic functionality as I need. Feel free to create a plugin from the source code: https://gist.github.com/fkromer/42eb93cbb8e4a58e57fd4734e208e568