# Files not being written to mapped network drive on windows using python script

Tags: python, unc

I have a python script which accesses a mapped network drive on Windows OS and creates a file in the mapped location to write. Here's the code to write.

```
output_file = f"{output_dirPath}/{directory_name}{output_suffix}"


with open(output_file, 'w') as file:
    file.write("Sample Name\tFilename\tSample Type\tProcessing Setting\tReference\n")
    for path in file_paths:
        file_name = os.path.basename(path)  # Extract the file name from the path
        final_filename = os.path.splitext(file_name)[0]  # Remove the .bam extension
        file.write(f"{final_filename}\t{path}\t{sample_type}\t{processing_setting}\t{reference}\n")
```

Where, output_dirPath is the mapped network drive which I am accessing as below

```
output_dirPath = "//abc/data/lab/Archives/Test/{}".format(directory_name)
```

Directory name is can be any alphanumeric string with spaces, _, and - in them.

The output suffix is `_template.txt`

When I run this script the section of the code (not mentioned here runs and unzips the files) however does not write to a file and gives following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Template.py", line 76, in <module>
    with open(output_file, 'w') as file:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '//abc/data/lab/Archives/Test/Output Folder abc 1ef3D00.example/Output Folder abc 1ef3D00.example_bamTemplate.txt'
```

Comment: We need debug info; what's in `output_dirPath`? `directory_name`? `output_suffix`?

Comment: output_dirPath is //abc/data/lab/Archives/Test/Output Folder abc 1ef3D00.example, directory_name is  Output Folder abc 1ef3D00.example, and output_suffix is _bamTemplate.txt

Comment: I think there is more code here than needed. How about a 2 liner. Asssign `output_file` and then a second line that is just `open(output_file, 'w')`. It doesn't matter what those extra variables are because the error happens before they are used.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Python, how can I access a shared folder on windows network?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7169845/using-python-how-can-i-access-a-shared-folder-on-windows-network)