Python unable to find file in network directory
I'm trying to open an image from a folder in my network, but python can't find it.
It is a PySimpleGUI small app that shows images.
This is the code related:
img1 = os.path.join(values['-FOLDER-'], img) 
window['IMAGE1'].update(data=convert_to_bytes(img1))

And this is the error it throws:
No such file or directory: '\\\\XXXX.XXXX.XXXX.XXXX\\folder\\image.jpg'  
The path is correct and the file does exists.
I have tried doing the same with images localy in my pc and it does work, so I'm guessing the problem is related to accessing the folder in the network.
I can open the folder and the image with the file explorer, after entering user and password to open the folder, I checked the remember credentials box so my user should have acces to it.
What could I do to solve this?
Thanks.

Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7170008/12576990

I solved this using pywin32 library and creating a connection to the shared drive.
import win32net    
data = {
    'remote': r'\\XX.XX.XX.XX\Folder', 
    'local': '',
    'username': 'username',
    'password': 'password'
}
win32net.NetUseAdd(None, 2, data)

